# How to delete a locked folder on Mac?

Tags: mac, permissions, finder, root, user-folders

I have been trying to remove a locked folder from my Mac. I am logged in as admin.

When I try to delete it from Finder, it says

> The operation can’t be completed because the item “X” is locked.

I have tried deleting it from the terminal by booting into recovery mode.

I have started my Mac using a Linux Live CD, mounted the Mac partition and tried removing it. Still no success.

I have also used:

> chmod ugo+w .
>
> chattr -i -a .

Also tried booting into single user mode to remove the folder. No luck.

Comment: If you have admin privileges, you can [follow these steps](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/11/lock-files-and-folders-in-mac-os-x/) to unlock the folder.  It may ask you for an admin password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the folder you want unlock from the Finder of the Mac
2. Go to the File menu and choose “Get Info” (or hit Command+i)
3. Look under ‘General’ and click the ‘Locked’ checkbox so that it’s
       unselected, this will unlock the folder

Comment: When I try to do that the checkbox is checked and the text 'Locked' is grayed out. This is after unlocking the Get Info panel.